# Formula Misbehaves in Word Table =SUM(ABOVE)

Tags: microsoft-word, worksheet-function

I've just discovered that with a specific situation, the `=SUM(ABOVE)` formula will misbehave... At least it's misbehaving as far as I can tell...

Produce a 3x3 table, with the bottom-left two cells merged and fill like so:

[image: table layout]

Believe it or not, that equation will come out to `5`... `2 + 3`.

[image: table result]

I've confirmed this by changing those values, and the issue appears to be [exacerbated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgEA7.png) by more merged columns.

---

The following will all result in the correct `3` being produced:

- Remove the merge
- Remove the top row
- Insert a row directly above - note: with or without a number in it
- Insert a number into the top row
- Insert an empty column between the `2` and `3` - note: without a number in it

---

Am I missing something, or do we have to be very careful when using merged cells and formulae?

Is there something more correct than `ABOVE` to use here?

I'm using Word 2013.

---

My solution for now is to simply avoid merged cells, and keep the column counts the same throughout - even if they aren't aligned:

[image: misaligned columns]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, merged cells will mess with its mind. An alternative to use specific cell numbers.

[image]

If you want to mix the use of "ABOVE" with explicit cell references the formula could look like:

**{ =SUM(ABOVE+A2) }** and in the above example the summed value would become **4**. Simple addition or subtraction can be used in this way. There is a PRODUCT function for multiplication and division.

The ABOVE function has some limitation, including stopping when a blank cell or a cell containing text is encountered. For further information on summing an entire column of numbers and working around the function's limitations, here is a link to an article on the Word MVP website entitled, "[How to get a formula to total an entire table column, even if some cells in the column contain text or are blank.](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/TotalColumn.htm)"

Comment: I didn't realise that was an option - thanks! Is there an easy way to do the similar ("_everything above this cell_") with explicit cell references?

Comment: @Attie I've added another example that hopefully answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @Rich... I was really wondering if there was a "_use all the cells above this row, in Column C_"... akin to `C1:C2` that would grow if rows were inserted - e.g: becoming `C1:C3`.. this doesn't appear to happen automatically, instead behaving more like `$C$1:$C$2`

Comment: @Attie the ABOVE function is not a static range. The range grows as rows are added, as long as the content of the cells above are numeric.

Comment: I've just found out today that Excel plays poorly with merged cells and references too... _sigh_